# Digital clock not updating dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a web page that includes a digital clock and date display. However, I've encountered an issue where the digital clock doesn't update dynamically; it only updates when the page is refreshed. Here's the relevant JavaScript code I'm using:

```
 function updateDigitalClock() {
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var minutes = now.getMinutes();
        var seconds = now.getSeconds();

       
        hours = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

        var digitalClock = document.getElementById('digital-clock');
        digitalClock.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }

  
    function updateDate() {
        var now = new Date();
        var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
        var dateElement = document.getElementById('date');
        dateElement.innerHTML = now.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    }
```

Could someone please help me identify why the digital clock is not updating dynamically and suggest a solution?

Comment: First off, add your HTML and turn it into a snippet (its the `<>` button when editing your post), secondly, there is no timeout or the like in order to update the clock periodically in your code. You still need _to tell the page when to call your functions and update_, the page can't figure that out for you.

Comment: Based on what is shown here, it could be that these functions are not even called. Could you share more of your code, place where you are calling these functions?

Comment: The clock isn't updating because there's no event calling the function. Have a look at this snippet on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock), in particular the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateClockAndDate() {
    updateDigitalClock();
    updateDate();
    
    // Request next animation
    requestAnimationFrame(updateClockAndDate);
}

// call to start the animation loop
updateClockAndDate();
```

**You can also use this**